# How do I position a div after the others?

Tags: html, css

So I have multiple divs. Like this:

```
<div id="LeftContent"></div>
<div id="RightContent"></div>
```

And so on. My goal is to create a centered div after all that. When I try to, I end up with the div being in the empty spaces between the 'left' and 'right' divs. An answer with some CSS code would be most appreciated.

HTML5:

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<head>




<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>OneClickLearn</title>
</head>

<body>


<aside>

    <br>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus">Learn HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare">Learn CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus">Learn the Basics of Web Design</a></li>
        <hr class="nav">
        <li><a href="#nowhere" class="denied" title="Pellentesque fermentum dolor">Learn PHP</a></li>
        <li><a href="#nowhere" class="denied" title="Pellentesque fermentum dolor">Learn JAVASCRIPT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>
  <a id="nav-toggle" href="#" class="position"><span></span></a>
<main>
  <header>
    <div href="#" class="container">
      <h1 class="title">OneClickLearn</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
</main>


<div class="header">
    <div class="content">
        <h1 class="large">Welcome To OneClickLearn</h1>
        <hr class="hr">
        <h2>A website for web developers everywhere</h2>
        </div>
    </div>



<div class="left">
    <h1>What you can do with us</h1>
    <h3>OneClickLearn offers several web design courses, as well as tools like <a href="#">Cascading Style Sheet</a> libraries, and special colors to use for your website! Unlike some other coding websites, OneClickLearn is absolutely free!</h3>
    <a class="abutton"><button>Learn More</button></a>
    </div>

<div>  
<div class="right">
    <h1>CSS Libraries</h1>
    <h3>What's a <a href="#">CSS Library</a>? Simple. This tool is made for web developers who are advanced in website functionality, but maybe not so great in what we would call, 'the pretties'. A CSS library is all the tools in design you need-- waiting for you on the web.</h3>
    <a class="abutton"><button>Learn More</button></a>
    <a class="abutton"><button class="buttonop">Get Ocelot.css</button></a>
</div>

    </div>

<div class="left">
    <h1>Courses</h1>
    <h3>All our courses (so far!) are based off of web design. With these courses, you learn the basics of HTML5, CSS3, and more languages coming soon. Also, you can learn our Cascading Style Sheet libraries' functions. If you have any reccomendations, just email us down below</h3>
    <a class="abutton"><button>Email Us</button></a>
    <a class="abutton"><button class="buttonop">Learn More</button></a>
    </div>


<div class="div">
    <h1>Having trouble with your website?</h1>
    <h3>We'll see what we can do.</h3>
    <a href="mailto:oneclicklearnteam@hmail.com"><button class="abutton">Contact Us</button></a>
    </div>    

</body>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/nav.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

.div {
        clear: both;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 100px;
        width: 600px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .greyback {
        background-color: #4B4949;
    }

    .nav {
        background-color: #bdc3c7;
    }

    .denied {
        color: #bdc3c7;
    }

    .denied:hover {
        cursor: not-allowed;
    }

    body {
        size: 100%;
        display: cover;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    p a {
        color: #27ae60;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    p a:hover {
        color: #27ae60;
        text-decoration: underline;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .header {
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: #2980b9;
    }

    .content {
        margin-top: 70px;
        padding-top: 60px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .large {
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    .hr {
        width: 100px;
    }

    .left {
        margin: 20px;
        float: left;
        height: auto;
        width: 50%;
        color: #4B4949;
    }

    .right {
        margin: 20px;
        float: right;
        height: auto;
        width: 50%;
        color: #4B4949;
    }

    a {
        color: #2AABAD;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .side {
        margin: 20px;
    }

    .img {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    button {
        background-color: #2980b9;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5PX;
        height: 40px;
        width: auto;
        color: white;
    }

    button:hover {
        background-color: #3498db;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .abutton {
        color: none;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .buttonop {
        background-color: #3498db;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5PX;
        height: 40px;
        width: auto;
        color: white;
    }

    .buttonop:hover {
        background-color: #2980b9;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .main {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .main-content {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

P.S. I am using float:left; and float:right; for the left and right divs :)

Thanks :) (If I need any elaboration please let me know)

Comment: What CSS are you using now to put the other devs on the left and right sides? How you're doing this will decide how you need to do the final div.

Comment: @Adrian float:left; and float:right;

Comment: If you're using `float` for the other divs, you'll need to use `clear` for the final div to ensure it flows after the floating divs. However, using `float` is often problematic, and you might be better served using `display: inline-block` instead or even a [flexbox layout](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/an-animated-guide-to-flexbox-d280cf6afc35).

Comment: @Adrian I'd prefer to stick with what I'm using

Comment: Then like I said, you would use `clear` on the last div.

Comment: @adrian clear adds a scrollbar though :( I don't want that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you are asking, but you could try something like the following:

**Html**

```
<div id="LeftContent"></div>
<div id="RightContent"></div>
<div id="CentredDiv"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
    height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 400px;
}
#LeftContent,
#RightContent {
    float: left;
}
#CentredDiv {
    width: 800px;
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Want the div to be centered and after the other left and right divs

Comment: I don't think your question is clear enough then. Here is a jsfiddle with a float left and right. (Instead of two float: lefts)
https://jsfiddle.net/Lbuov6rc/

Comment: You got it too. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, not totally sure what you want, but maybe something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gb4anhwd/)?

```
#CenteredContent {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I edited your code a bit to something like this:  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  text-align:center; - But it worked

Comment: Glad to help.  I prefer to use flexbox, but I think the main thing you were missing was `clear:both` .  Extra code was added for visualization.

Comment: Actually, clear:both; adds a scrollbar (which I don't want) but it also makes the code work. Any help here?

Comment: well, I would have to see the actual code for your project.  Is there a parent div?  The width of your divs is probably what is causing this.

Comment: I would try adjusting the height of `<div class="header">` .  If the size/content of the three divs is greater than any of the parent divs you will most likely get a scrollbar.

Comment: To what should I adjust it to?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you need a centered div. You can do this to achieve centered div.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="centered-div">
  Some Content
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.centered-div {
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
}
```

I hope that helps :)

Comment: I would like to know how many people understand the question so I can eleborate

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to ask. It would be easier to understand if you could post a screenshot of your output.

Comment: Here I have created a JSFiddle for you. https://jsfiddle.net/s7vdhd6g/2/